# Dynamic Keyword Arguments in Python?

Tags: python

Does python have the ability to create dynamic keywords?

For example:

```
qset.filter(min_price__usd__range=(min_price, max_price))
```

I want to be able to change the **usd** part based on a selected currency.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310732/in-django-how-does-one-filter-a-queryset-with-dynamic-field-lookups

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Yes, It does. Use `**kwargs` in a function definition.

Example:

```
def f(**kwargs):
    print kwargs.keys()


f(a=2, b="b")     # -> ['a', 'b']
f(**{'d'+'e': 1}) # -> ['de']
```

But why do you need that?

Comment: Thanks, that did it.
I needed this because I don't have access to the function itself (it's a Django function). So the method itself is already looking for **kwargs, but I need to dynamically create the keyword for the method to parse.

Answer (score 39):

If I understand what you're asking correctly,

```
qset.filter(**{
    'min_price_' + selected_currency + '_range' :
    (min_price, max_price)})
```

does what you need.

Answer (score 14):

You can easily do this by declaring your function like this:

```
def filter(**kwargs):
```

your function will now be passed a dictionary called kwargs that contains the keywords and values passed to your function.  Note that, syntactically, the word `kwargs` is meaningless; the `**` is what causes the dynamic keyword behavior.

You can also do the reverse.  If you are calling a function, and you have a dictionary that corresponds to the arguments, you can do

```
someFunction(**theDictionary)
```

There is also the lesser used *foo variant, which causes you to receive an array of arguments.  This is similar to normal C vararg arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sort of.
In your filter method you can declare a wildcard variable that collects all the unknown  [keyword arguments](http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/tut/node6.html#SECTION006720000000000000000). Your method might look like this:

```
def filter(self, **kwargs):
    for key,value in kwargs:
        if key.startswith('min_price__') and key.endswith('__range'):
            currency = key.replace('min_price__', '').replace('__range','')
            rate = self.current_conversion_rates[currency]
            self.setCurrencyRange(value[0]*rate, value[1]*rate)
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I don't have access to the function itself (it's a Django function).  So the method itself is already looking for **kwargs, but I need to dynamically create the keyword for the method to parse.