# is it possible to define name of function's arguments dynamically?

Tags: python, django

Now I have this code:

```
        attitude = request.REQUEST['attitude']
        if attitude == 'want':
            qs = qs.filter(attitudes__want=True)
        elif attitude == 'like':
            qs = qs.filter(attitudes__like=True)
        elif attitude == 'hate':
            qs = qs.filter(attitudes__hate=True)
        elif attitude == 'seen':
            qs = qs.filter(attitudes__seen=True)
```

It's will be better to define name of "attitudes__xxxx" dynamically. Is there any ways to do that ?

Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/353489/cleaner-way-to-query-on-a-dynamic-number-of-columns-in-django

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.

```
qs.filter( **{ 'attitudes__%s'%arg:True } )
```

Comment: Thank you! Your case, little modified, works correctly: qs.filter( **{ 'attitudes__%s' % str(attitude): True } )

Comment: The str(attitude) is redundant -- the %s formatting already does that! So S.Lott's answer is perfect and indeed better than your "little modified" variant.