# Django queryset dynamic filtering

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a query that looks like this:

```
cls.objects.filter(name__in=lookup_values).values():
```

The problem is that sometimes I want to filter by `name` but other times I want to filter by, say, `officer_number` or `customer_number`. Is there a way for me to dynamically set the `whatever__in` part of the query so it's not hard-coded?

Comment: see - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310732/in-django-how-does-one-filter-a-queryset-with-dynamic-field-lookups - e.g. kwargs = {'%s__%s' % ('name', 'in'): 'A'} ?

Answer (score 10):

Do you mean something like:

```
args = {'id__in':[1]}

qs = Something.objects.filter(**args)
```

Comment: No, JamesO actually linked us up with a duplicate of this question. I voted to close mine.