# Specifying Django Query Filters at Run Time

Tags: python, django, runtime, django-queryset

How do I specify an arbitrary Django query filter at runtime?

Normally one uses filters like so...

```
query_set = MyModel.objects.filter(name__iexact='foobar')
```

But what if I have the query filter specifier contained in a string?

```
query_specifier = "name_iexact='foobar'"
query_set = MyModel.objects.filter(query_specifier) # <-- This doesn't work; How can I do this?
```

Comment: This is also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310732/in-django-how-does-one-filter-a-queryset-with-dynamic-field-lookups

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
query_specifier = {
    'name__iexact': 'foobar'
}
query_set = MyModel.objects.filter(**query_specifier)
```

Comment: This works because Django *is* python, and **query_specifier will be unpacked. Here's a related post about kwargs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769403/understanding-kwargs-in-python