# django dynamically filtering with q objects

Tags: django, django-models, django-q

I'm trying to query a database based on user input tags. The number of tags can be from 0-5, so I need to create the query dynamically.

So I have a tag list, tag_list, and I want to query the database:

```
design_list = Design.objects.filter(Q(tags__tag__contains = "tag1") and Q(tags__tag__contains = "tag2") and etc. etc. )
```

How can I create this feature?

Answer (score 129, accepted):

You'll want to loop through the tag_list and apply a filter for each one.

```python
tag_list = ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3']
base_qs = Design.objects.all()
for t in tag_list:
    base_qs = base_qs.filter(tags__tag__contains=t)
```

This will give you results matching *all* tags, as your example indicated with `and`. If in fact you needed `or` instead, you will probably need Q objects.

**Edit:** I think I have what you're looking for now.

```python
tags = ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3']
q_objects = Q() # Create an empty Q object to start with
for t in tags:
    q_objects |= Q(tags__tag__contains=t) # 'or' the Q objects together

designs = Design.objects.filter(q_objects)
```

I tested this and it seems to work really well.

**Edit 2:** Credit to kezabelle in #django on Freenode for the initial idea.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I've tried it with Q objects, but it doesn't return the correct items. Is there anything I'm doing wrong here: `        design_list = Design.objects.all()
        for t in tag_list:
            design_list = design_list.filter(Q(tags__tag__contains = t))`. It works when there's only one tag, but no more.

Comment: In your code there, the Q object is not doing anything. You're simple creating a queryset that, in the end, looks like ``Design.objects.filter(tags__tag__contains='tag1').filter(tags__tag__contains='tag2')``, etc. What you probably want instead is ``Design.objects.filter(Q(tags__tag__contains='tag1') | Q(tags__tag__contains='tag2'))``, but in a way gives you a variable number of Q objects.

Comment: Ok, that's what I need to look for.

Comment: If you want `designs` to be empty when `tags` is empty, you can use `Q(pk__in=[])` as a starting value for `q_objects`.

Comment: It's a shame the QuerySet API doesn't have an "any" method that takes a list of Q objects with "or" semantics, the way filter/exclude/get can take a list of Q objects with "and" semantics.

Comment: I'm new to this, but I managed to get two examples working: https://gist.github.com/odigity/53bf47cca9a238a905c276760153838d

Comment: Is concatenating Q objects with a single call to filter *faster* than sequentially filtering as in your first example?

Answer (score 43):

You can use this way:

```
my_dict = {'field_1': 1, 'field_2': 2, 'field_3': 3, ...}  # Your dict with fields
or_condition = Q()
for key, value in my_dict.items():
    or_condition.add(Q(**{key: value}), Q.OR)

query_set = MyModel.objects.filter(or_condition)
```

By this way you can use dynamically generated field names. 
Also you can use `Q.AND` for `AND` condition.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with `__in`? Like to get a Q that matches a field to a list of values, where the name of the field and the list of values are given by variables instead of literals?

Comment: @MichaelHoffmann I do not quite understand what you mean, maybe this:
Q(**{"{}__in".format(key): value})

Comment: Excellent.  Would this single call to  `filter` be faster than calling filter for each condition?

Answer (score 3):

Just prepare a tag list first then, query like this:

```
tags = ['tag1', 'tag2',...]
design_list = Design.objects.filter(tags__tag__contains__in = tags)
```

Answer (score 2):

You may need to add AND and OR conditions

```
    query = (Q(fild1='ENABLE'))
    # Filter by list
    query.add(Q(fild2__in=[p.code for p in Objects.field.all()]), Q.AND)

    # filter OR
    q_objects = Q(field3='9999999')
    for x in myList:
        q_objects.add(Q(field3=x.code), Q.OR)

    query.add(q_objects, Q.AND)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use reduce :

```
from functools import reduce
design_list = Design.objects.filter(reduce(lambda q1,q2: q1 & q2,
                                           [Q(tags__tag__contains=t)
                                            for t in tag_list]))
```