# How to query the fields which contains comma seperated values in db?

Tags: django

I have a table called **Demo** which consits of two fields i.e;

**Name,hobbies**. hobbies contains comma seperated values in db.

for example: "eating,sleeping,dancing"

now i have to query for the field hobbies which contains "eating,sleeping".

I have tried

```
Demo.object.get(hobbies__in=['eating','sleeping'])
```

I am getting

> matching query does not exists

How can i solve this

Comment: This is not how the IN operator works in SQL

Comment: Did you try to google the error? It happens because you use `get` and there are no such objects in your database. You should use `filter` if you do not know for a fact that the object exists. Additionally, the query is incorrect.

Comment: show your deom models please, can you use [commaseparatedintegerfield](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#commaseparatedintegerfield)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you can guarantee the order of the two values, then you have to use contains. This translates to `LIKE '%eating%'` and `LIKE '%sleeping%'`.

Example:

```
demos = Demo.object.filter(hobbies__contains='eating', hobbies__contains='sleeping')
```

Comment: can we make it dynamic?

Comment: Sure, you can also do `hobbies__contains=my_variable`. You can also see a simple example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13076894/921563 If you have problems with it I advice you to Google the problem and if you are not able to solve it, then open a new question.