# Django variable number of filters on ManyToManyField objects?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I'd like to filter objects on a ManyToManyField using two attributes of the objects that is pointed to by ManyToManyFeild. See the model below, this is a classical user-items relationship

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
#    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=False, default=None, unique=True)
    ratings = models.ManyToManyField('Rating',
        related_name="persons"
    )


class Movie(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=False, default=None, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title}"

class Rating(models.Model):
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie, models.CASCADE)
    value = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=False, null=False, default=None)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.movie}:{self.value}"
```

So, I'd like to find all users who gave above certain rating to Movie1 AND above certain rating to Movie2.

I can do this with cascading filters:

```
>>> Person.objects\
 .filter(ratings__movie__title='Movie1', ratings__value__gte=5)\
 .filter(ratings__movie__title='Movie2', ratings__value__gte=1)\
 .all()
[[A<QuerySet [<Person: Person object (1)>]>
```

But I am looking for a way to filter on any arbitrary number of ratings, not just 2.

I have tried with Q (in the case single `filter()` for all cases), but the following doesn't work:

```
>>> Person.objects.filter(
  Q(ratings__movie__title='Movie1') & Q(ratings__value__gte=5),\
  Q(ratings__movie__title='Movie2') & Q(ratings__value__gte=1)
).all()
<QuerySet []>
```

**Update:**

I figured out, that since filters are lazy, I could cascade a required number of them them in a loop and then call `.all()` in the end, like this:

```py
my_filters = [("Movie1", 2), ("Movie2", 3)]
f = Person.objects
for m,r in my_filters:
  f = f.filter(ratings__movie__title=m, ratings__value__gte=r)

selected_persons = f.all()
```

The question of course remains, how efficient is that query... So the question remains on how to do this with the best efficiency.

Thanks for help!

Comment: You can dynamically generate some Q objects. Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13076894/4151233

Comment: yes, but I struggle to make a correct Q expression for my case. The one I gave at the end render empty set, while the one with cascading filters works ok.

Answer (score 0):

You want to or the Q objects your current attempt and's them, which basically means the movie title must be Movie1 AND Movie2 and the rating must be 5 AND 1.
This might work as you want:-

```
Person.objects.filter(
  (Q(ratings__movie__title='Movie1') & Q(ratings__value__gte=5)) | (Q(ratings__movie__title='Movie2') & Q(ratings__value__gte=1))
).all()
```

Comment: But I think this means I search for users who either give >=rating1 to movie1 OR >=rating2 to movie2, but I want to search for users who reviewed both Movie1 and Movie2 and gave them respectively above rating1 and rating2.

Comment: In that case your approach with the cascading filters is the only one I can think of. As even if we think just about the SQL the only way I can think is multiple joins on the ratings table. Also why have you setup a many to many field in Person a better approach would be to put a foreign key to Person in Rating.

Comment: Yes, you are right about the fereign key. I guess I need to rethink the model, since the search case I outlined is the my main goal...