# django filter when the some of the arguments are null

Tags: python, django, filter

I'm now using django filter to get the queryset I want,here is my code:

```
             students = Student.objects.filter(
                sales=current_user,
                nickname = form_data['nickname'],
                mobile = form_data['mobile'],
                gender = form_data['gender'],
                state = form_data['state'],
                source = form_data['source'],
                register_at = form_data['register_at'],
                importance = form_data['importance'],
                remaining = form_data['remaining'],
                level = form_data['level'],
                feature = form_data['feature'],
                company_name = form_data['company']
            ).order_by(register_order, remaining_order, level_order)
```

now the question is :some of my form data fields may be null, cause the forms are input by the user, and he/she can choose to just input some fields, I wonder if this code could work when some fields are null, if not, how to rewrite it to get the queryset based on the fields user inputs?

Comment: You should not use `form_data`, but use `form.cleaned_data` to get valid data.

Comment: Might be duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310732/in-django-how-does-one-filter-a-queryset-with-dynamic-field-lookups

Comment: well I didn't paste the form_data = some_form(request.GET)， I‘m doing this query in the get_queryset in a ListView

Comment: I'm afraid it's not the same case

Comment: form = some_form(request.GET), form_data = form.cleaned_data  ,sorry

Comment: you could filter `form_data`, excluding all keys that have `None` valu, and then pass the dictionary to `filter()` like `filter(**clean_form_data)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logic could be like this:

```
# start with this
students = Student.objects.filter(sales=current_user)

value = form.cleaned_data.get('nickname', None)
if value is not None:
    students = students.filter(nickname=value)

# etc, etc ...

# end with that
students = students.order_by(register_order, remaining_order, level_order)
```

But of course, this would be ugly considering how many fields you have. Instead, you could have something like this:

```
students = Student.objects.filter(sales=current_user)
    
fields = ['nickname', 'mobile', 'gender', ....]
for field in fields:
    value = form.cleaned_data.get(field, None)
    if value is not None:
        students = students.filter(**{field: value})
    
students = students.order_by(register_order, remaining_order, level_order)
```

Or, using **all fields of the form**:

```
students = Student.objects.filter(sales=current_user)
    
for key, value in form.cleaned_data.items():
    if value is not None:
        students = students.filter(**{key: value})
    
students = students.order_by(register_order, remaining_order, level_order)
```

Note that we're testing `if value is not None` instead of just `if value`, this is to allow '0' values to pass the test.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I chose the 3rd way:)