# Python/Django -- what is the difference between the "and" operator and the "&" operator

Tags: python, django, operator-keyword

I have a interesting Django problem.

Consider the following:

```
Model.objects.filter(Q(id='test1') and Q(id='test2'))
```

this returns the expected results, however

```
Model.objects.filter(Q(id='test1') & Q(id='test2'))
```

DOES NOT!!

What's going on here?

Comment: What result does the & produce?

Comment: It results in an empty set

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845018/python-boolean-operators-vs-bitwise-operators and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects

Comment: @kgu87  So how can I create a tupe of (Q(one) and Q(two)) dynamically from a [one, two] list?  Is that possible?

Answer (score 4):

If you want Django ORM to return test1 and test2, you should use :

```
Model.objects.filter(Q(id='test1') | Q(id='test2'))
```

`Model.objects.filter(Q(id='test1') & Q(id='test2'))` means return model objects whose id is test1 while its is test2 at the same time. Of course, django will return an empty QuerySet.

**and** is a [boolean operator](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not) in Python. For operation `x and y` the result is `if x is false, then x, else y`. Thus `Q(id='test1') and Q(id='test2')` equals `Q(id='test1')`, it is not what you want.

**&/|** is the the [bitwise and/or operator](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__or__#object.__or__).

BTW, there's no way to override the boolean operator, but you can override `&/|` operators in your class by define a method named `__and__` / `__or__`.

below is the source code of the django Q object[[github]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/query_utils.py):

```
class Q(tree.Node):
    """
    Encapsulates filters as objects that can then be combined logically (using
    & and |).
    """
    # Connection types
    AND = 'AND'
    OR = 'OR'
    default = AND

    def __or__(self, other):
        return self._combine(other, self.OR)

    def __and__(self, other):
        return self._combine(other, self.AND)
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

according to the following [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_basic_operators.htm)

& is a Binary AND Operator copies a bit to the result if it exists in both operands.

Example:
Assume if a = 60; and b = 13; Now in binary format they will be as follows:

a = 0011 1100

b = 0000 1101

(a & b) will give 12 which is 0000 1100

and Called Logical AND operator. If both the operands are true then then condition becomes true.

Example: (a and b) is true.

So the & was performing binary addition on your query set. Interesting.

Comment: Ok, so my main problem is that I have a list of search params, that I need to dynamically create a (Q(one) and Q(two)) from a list [one, two].  I can't use reduce(operator.and_, Q(i) for i in LIST)) because and_ is bitwise!!! So what can I do??

Comment: My django knowledge is still pretty limited but this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310732/in-django-how-does-one-filter-a-queryset-with-dynamic-field-lookups) looks similar to what your looking for. Sorry i cant be of more help. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `OR` here, and not `AND`

```
filters = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4']
filtered = Model.objects.filter(Q(id = filters[0]))
for f in filters[1:]:
     subset = Model.objects.filter(Q(id = f))
     filtered = filtered | subset
```