# Django kwargs expansion not working with startswith

Tags: python, django, database, filter, keyword-argument

I was facing a problem very similar to [question 310732](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310732/in-django-how-does-one-filter-a-queryset-with-dynamic-field-lookups) and following the advice there, I implemented the .format() solution in my kwargs generation.

A dump of a small example looks like this:

```
{'username_fragment_1__startswith': u'joey'}
```

where "username_fragment_1" is a valid column name.

More details per Daniel's request:

```
query_sub = "(CASE WHEN ISNULL(%s) THEN 0 ELSE LENGTH(%s) END)"

query_string = query_sub % ((label_dict[frag],)*2)

results[frag] = DisplayNameSearchResult.objects.filter(**kwargs).extra(select={ 'proxylen':(query_string)},order_by=['proxylen']).values('agent_id', 'proxylen')
```

However, when I run the unit tests, I get:

```
OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'username_fragment_1__startswith' in 'field list'")
```

The call in views.py looks something like:

```
MyClass.objects.filter(**kwargs)
```

Suggestions appreciated.

Comment: If you remove the `__startswith`, does it still work?

Comment: Yes, but then the query becomes exact instead of like.

Comment: Please show the exact call, rather than one that "looks something like" it.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: Added more details in summary.

Comment: can you try removing `extra(select={ 'proxylen':(query_string)},order_by=['proxylen']).values('agent_id', 'proxylen')`, see if it works?

Comment: @eugene: Yeah, I tried that too, at the time.  The  processing failed at the filter, so it never even got to the extra part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And now, this morning it is working with no changes.  Closing as a heisenbug.