# django filter field as a string

Tags: django, python-3.x

i want to change the filtering field dynamically.

i have a model named `Product` and fields are `title` and `code`

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

my filtering field will be dynamic in views like this

```
def filter(request):

    search_choices = {
        '1': 'title__icontains',
        '2': 'code__icontains',
        }

    col_num = request.GET.get("col_num")
    value = request.GET.get("value")

    search_field = search_choices.get("col_num")

    qs = Product.objects.filter(search_field=value)

    ........
```

here the variable `search_field` is always dynamic ... so how can i achieve this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Django, how does one filter a QuerySet with dynamic field lookups?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310732/in-django-how-does-one-filter-a-queryset-with-dynamic-field-lookups)

Comment: @ramganesh thankyou for your answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this by passing argument as dictionary:

```
value = request.GET.get("value")
search_field = search_choices.get("col_num")
qs = Product.objects.filter(**{search_field: value})
```