# Django: How to depend on an externally ID, which can be switched?

Tags: django, database, rdbms

Consider the following scenario:

Our Django database objects must rely on IDs that are provided by external service A (`ESA`) - this is because we use this ID to pull the information about objects that aren't created yet from the external directly. `ESA` might shut down soon, so we also pull information about the same objects from external service B (`ESB`), and save them as a fallback.

Because these IDs are relied on heavily in views and URLs, the ideal scenario would be to use a @property:

```
@property
dynamic_id = ESA_id
```

And then, if `ESA` shuts down, we can switch easily by changing `dynamic_id` to `ESB_id`. The problem with this though, is that properties cannot be used in queryset filters and various other scenarios, which is also a must in this case.

My current thought is to just save ESA_id, ESB_id, and dynamic_ID as regular fields separately and assign `dynamic_ID = ESA_id`, and then, in case `ESA` shuts down, simply go over the objects and do `dynamic_ID = ESB_id`.

But I feel there must be a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having ESA_id and ESB_id fields in the same table is a good solution, then you have some kind of setting (DEFAULT_SERVICE_ID='ESA_id'|'ESB_id') and your code change the lookup based on this option.

Here you can see an aproach to create filters dynamicly
https://stackoverflow.com/a/310785/1448667

Comment: Thanks. I do have them both in the database. The question is how to refer to them dynamically - meaning, if ESA went down, how can I switch to ESB with changing the references in the views.

Comment: The second part of my answwer was meant to give you a solution, wich I failed to do ;) If you change the querysets of your views to have the reference to the id you are using at the momtent it will do the trick.