# Django: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: django, django-queryset

I am new in Django.

In my Django view.py, I have following get method: `customer_list = Customer.objects.filter(CustId = '1001')` and it returns result.

When I substitute with a String like following:

```py
getQueryString = "CustId = '1001'"
customer_list = Customer.objects.filter(getQueryString)
```

I get the following error:

> too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Any help really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using a dict?

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/310785/7395911), perhaps it can help you understand your problem.

```py
getQueryString = {'CustId': '1001'}
customer_list = Customer.objects.filter(**getQueryString)
```

Comment: I tried dict as well. It worked. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Deysgroup You're welcome! Also, don't forget to mark as an answer ;D

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Deysgroup if you want send like that you can use `getQueryString={'CustId': '1001'}` and then call the function using `customer_list = Customer.objects.filter(**getQueryString)`, I hope that this answer helps you.