# How to set a dynamic field name in a objects.get() function

Tags: django, django-models

I want to create a mixin that allows me to change the field of a `get` function as follows:

```
class MyMixin(self):

    myfield = 'field1' 

    def myfunct(self):

        i = MyModel.objects.get(self.myfield=myvar)
```

Such that the desired code runs `MyModel.objects.get(field1=myvar)`.

However, this approach returns

> SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment

How can I set field names like this dynamically?

Comment: Possible Duplicate [In Django, how does one filter a QuerySet with dynamic field lookups?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310732/in-django-how-does-one-filter-a-queryset-with-dynamic-field-lookups)

Answer (score 4):

You could do it like this:

```py
kwargs = {self.myfield: myvar}
MyModel.objects.get(**kwargs)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a 2-tuple to a [**`Q`** object <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Q) with a key and a value:

```
from django.db.models import Q

MyModel.objects.get(Q((self.myfield, myvar)))
```

For example, we can generate a query for the `.filter(..)`:

```
>>> print(MyModel.objects.filter(Q(('id', 1))).query)
SELECT `test_mymodel`.`id` FROM `test_mymodel` WHERE `test_mymodel`.`id` = 1
```

In fact, if you take a look at how Django processes the positional and named parameters of the `.get(..)` and `.filter(..)`, [it makes a `Q` object <sup>[GitHub]</sup>](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.0.x/django/db/models/query.py#L919-L924):

> ```
>         …
>         clone = self._chain()
>         if negate:
>             clone.query.add_q(~Q(*args, **kwargs))
>         else:
>             clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
>         return clone
> ```

and the named parameters are [converted to (sorted) 2-tuples](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.0.x/django/db/models/query_utils.py#L58-L59):

> ```
> class Q(tree.Node):
>     # …
>
>         def __init__(self, *args, _connector=None, _negated=False, **kwargs):
>             super().__init__(children=[*args, *sorted(kwargs.items())], connector=_connector,
> negated=_negated)
> ```

so by using a 2-tuple in a Q object, we make a "shortcut" so to speak.

Answer (score 0):

```
lookup_kwargs = {'{0}'.format('id'): 1}
People.objects.get(**lookup_kwargs)
```

**N.B:** *Your dynamic lookup field must exit in the following model. Otherwise, you will get an error, like (django.core.exceptions.FieldError......).*

In the same way, you can filter single or multiple fields based on your expectations

```
lookup_kwargs = {'{0}'.format('id'): 1}
People.objects.filter(**lookup_kwargs)
```